# Optional hql query parameters

Tags: spring, spring-data, hql

I have on a rest repository:

```
@Query(
            "SELECT ord FROM Order as ord where " +
                    " (:#{#customer} is null or :#{#customer}='' or  ord.customer = :#{#customer}) and " +
                    " (:#{#supplier} is null or :#{#supplier}='' or ord.supplier = :#{#supplier} ) and " +
                    " (:#{#startDate} is null or :#{#startDate}='' or ord.date >= :#{#startDate} ) and " +
                    " (:#{#endDate} is null or :#{#endDate}='' or ord.date >= :#{#endDate} )"
    )
    Page<Order> query(
            @Param("customer") Organization customer,
            @Param("supplier") Organization supplier,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @Param("startDate") Date startDate,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @Param("endDate") Date endDate,
            Pageable pageable
    );
```

When I call the query without any parameters it works fine and returns every order. If I supply any one of the parameters but not the rest, I get `org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set`. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Do you set the parameter as `null`? Or you don't pass it at all

Comment: I use postman to test. Doesn't matter if I pass empty parameters like `&customer=&supplier...` or if I don't pass at all, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mixed SpEL for entity name and bind parameters . For binding use ':parameterName' not ':#{#parameterName} '

```
@Query(
            "SELECT ord FROM Order as ord where " +
                    " (:customer is null or :customer='' or  ord.customer = :customer) and " +
                    " (:upplier is null or supplier='' or ord.supplier = :supplier) and " +
                    " (:startDate is null or :startDate='' or ord.date >= :startDate) and " +
                    " (:endDate is null or :endDate='' or ord.date >= :endDate )"
    )
    Page<Order> query(
            @Param("customer") Organization customer,
            @Param("supplier") Organization supplier,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @Param("startDate") Date startDate,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @Param("endDate") Date endDate,
            Pageable pageable
    );
```